# asp.net editable autocomplete dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have a requirement of creating cool editable autocomplete filterable dropdownlist, which should look like a dropdownlist meaning an arrow key on right side on click of which it will show all the items in the dropdownlist and a editable textbox where user can type something and items in the dropdown will automatically get filtered.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options that can easily be found using a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net%20autocomplete%20dropdown#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net%20autocomplete%20dropdown&oq=asp.net%20autocomplete%20dropdown&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.2007.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.BKAkaXBoOdE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=caf26cc50dd30da&biw=1863&bih=1150).

Here's a freebie jQuery plugin that will give you what you want: [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)